# Place calls from Windows (7) using a SIM-card

Tags: windows-7, netbook, 3g, gsm

So, I have a built-in Globetrotter SIM module in my netbook that allows me to access the internet over 3G. The software that comes with it also allows me to send and receive text messages. However, I'd like to be able to make calls with it over the 3G/GSM network as well. Do you know of any (software) solutions to make this possible?

Comment: why wouldn't Skype or Google Voice work?

Comment: @Studiohack it won't function when only GPRS (not 3G) is available due to too low speeds for example, whereas a just being connected to a cellular network you could still make calls independent of the connection type.

Comment: You may want to ask your service provider this question.

Comment: @ZianChoy What has my service provider got to do with this?

Comment: Most SIM cards provided with laptops as deals are only activated for data services. You'd need to contact the provider and arrange a voice contract with them to make a normal GSM phone call with that SIM. Voice calls over data (like Skype, however) don't normally require permissions from the network.

Comment: @GAThrawn really, that is not the question here, I'm using my normal SIM card that I use to call with as well...

Comment: @Blood you could mention that in the question ;)

Comment: @GAThrawn it has nothing to do with my question... I'm talking about hard- or software...

Comment: @RhysGibson DUDES! Read my lips, IM USING MY PHONE'S SIM CARD. Im not having issues with my SIM card here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually 3G USB internet modems do not provide functionality to place calls, although you may find a similar device which would enable this

Have a look at these solutions: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/VOIP+GSM+Gateways

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. I have used my Acer 1420p to make phone calls. Here is how: http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/482532-enabling-ussd-voice-support-em770w-3g-module.html